# Angular js ng-options is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-options, but seems not to be working, I have been reading and reading about the topic and I have the same structure as it required but I'm getting the same result, hope you guys can help me.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-options="person.name for person in people">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.people = [
        { name: "My domain" },
        { name: "qe" },
        { name: "contact_base_esp" },
        { name: "Domain 1" },
        { name: "Domain 2" },
        { name: "this is a template" },
        { name: "Contact base esp" }
    ];
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/1005/

Comment: won't work without `ng-model` http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/1006/   See docs

Answer (score 0):

You've missed few bits please see demo below

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
    name: "My domain"
  }, {
    name: "Cobranza"
  }, {
    name: "contact_base_esp"
  }, {
    name: "Domain 1"
  }, {
    name: "Domain dos"
  }, {
    name: "Este es un template"
  }, {
    name: "Contact base esp"
  }];

  $scope.selected = $scope.people[0];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="person as person.name for person in people">
      <option value="Choose one"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```